# Fire onblur event before onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have a large form that contains several text input fields.  Essentially, I need to handle the `onchange` event for **all fields** and the `onblur` events for **some** fields.  When a change is made to a field and the field loses focus, both events fire (which is the correct behavior).  The only issue is that I would like to handle the `onblur`
 event before I handle the `onchange` event.

After some testing in ie and Firefox, it seems that the default behavior is to fire the `onchange` event before `onblur`.  I have been using the following code as a test...

```
<html>

<body >
    <input type="text" value="here is a text field" onchange="console.log('Change Event!')" onblur="console.log('Blur Event!')" >

</body>
</html>
```

Which brings me to my questions:

1. It seems that this behavior is consistent across browsers.  Why does `onchange` fire first?
2. Since I cannot handle the `onblur` event for every input element, is there a way I can get `onblur` to fire before handling the `onchange` event?

Comment: You have `jQuery` in your tags. Are you using it? If so, you can handle the events in any order you'd like by checking the `event.type` inside the handler.

Comment: @DevlshOne - But you cant change the order in which they are fired..

Comment: @DevlshOne I am using it in my actual project, so it could be used for a solution.

Comment: No, you can't but you can handle them in whatever order you want to.

Comment: Use a setTimeout call in your onchange calls to delay execution.

Comment: You might also consider using the `$.when()` method to make both calls and then act upon the responses in any order you wish.

Comment: @j08691 That would be unreliable unless you introduce a significant delay. alexsh's approach renders this unnecessary though.

Comment: It's important to note, [Blur and Change do not happen in any specific order](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2007/02/06/event-order-of-blur-and-change/).

Comment: @Richard You mean it is browser specific

Comment: @Asad - looks like I wasn't the only one with the timeout idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448944/jquery-how-to-fire-onclick-first-before-onblur?rq=1

Comment: @Joel Well, I'm sure it's reliable within a given browser.  But, if you're seeing blur/change be the same between IE and FF, then it sounds like it's also version specific (or OS specific or something else). ([Someone has seen a difference between browsers](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2007/02/06/event-order-of-blur-and-change/).)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. The reason `onchange` fires first is that once the element loses focus (i.e. 'blurs') the change is usually complete (I say usually because a script can still change the element without user interaction).
2. For those elements that need `onblur` handled first, you can disable the `onchange` handler and fire the `onchange` (or even a custom event) from the `onblur` handler. This will ensure the correct order even though it is more work. To detect change, you can use a state variable for that field.

As a general remark though, the need for such synchronicity is a sign that the approach you are using to solve whatever problem you are solving might need more work even though sometimes it cannot be avoided. If you are sure this is the only way, try one of these methods!

EDIT: Just to elaborate on the last point, you would have to follow some assumptions about your event model. Are you assuming that each `change` event is followed by a `blur` and goes unprocessed otherwise, or would you like to process each `change` but those that are followed by a `blur`get further processing after whatever `onblur` does with them? In any case if you want to enforce the order the handlers would need access to a common resource (global variable, property, etc.). Are there other event types you might want to use? (`input`?). Finally, this link has some details for the `change` event for Mozilla browsers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change.
The third 'bullet' addresses the issue of event order.

Comment: +1: "the need for such synchronicity is a sign that the approach you are using ... might need more work"

Comment: If I only handle the onblur event for those select elements, I will lose the ability to know if the field has been changed... hence the onchange handler.  Creating state variables for each field is not very trivial

Comment: @Joel Since `onchange` comes before, you can set a data-attribute on the element to indicate that the value has changed in an `onchange` handler, then read and clear this attribute in the `onblur` handler and act according to it.

Comment: I just added a comment to address precisely this issue. You can keep a state in a separate variable. A cleaner, though much more tedious approach would be to split the processing of the `onblur` event into two halves: the second one fired by the `onchange` and then return back to the second half of the `onchange` handler (this is probably and overkill though).

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of hack, but it seems to do the trick on most browsers:

```
<input type="text" value="Text Input" onchange="setTimeout(function(){console.log('Change Event!')}, 0);" onblur="console.log('Blur Event!');" />
```

You can see a fiddle of it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/XpPhE/

Here is a little background information on the `setTimeout(function, 0)` trick: http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'm not sure how reliable this would be. It doesn't sound like the spec would guarantee that event handler would be fired *before* a callback scheduled for right now using `setTimeout`, so you might just be relying on an implementation detail there.